# American rice vs rice of America

Tags: adjectives, of-genitive

The following is a question from the university entrance examination held in 1994 using the DNC Japan Test.

Can you tell the difference between rice grown in Japan and ?

1. American one, 2) American rice, 3) one of America, 4) rice of America

Correct answer is 2. I'd like to know why 4 is incorrect. If there were another option 4',

4') the rice of America

would 4' be also the correct answer? The reason why I think 4' might be right is that there is a book called *The Wines of America* by Leon D. Adams.

Comment: Neither 4 nor 4' is idiomatic. We speak of 'the plains of America', 'the people of America', but we don't refer to a country's produce in that way.

Comment: The answers are awful, if that helps for you to know. If we get to invent better answers, use "rice grown in Japan and that in America." (The) rice of  America is not normal.

Comment: We don't tend to use *of* in relation to countries. We're more likely to to use either *in* or *from*: *rice in America* or *rice from America*. Similarly *the most famous person in America*, not *the most famous person of America* etc.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore: There are [plenty](https://www.bankofamerica.com/) [of](https://www.mallofamerica.com/) [notable](https://www.voanews.com/) [exceptions](https://www.loa.org/), not to mention the [obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States) one. I think it's probably truer to say that "of America" is only (or mostly) used in specific circumstances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can one explain the different distributions of the Saxon and the analytic (Norman) (periphrastic, 'of') genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/can-one-explain-the-different-distributions-of-the-saxon-and-the-analytic-norma) Or [Are people using 'of' differently today than they were 20 years ago](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/are-people-using-of-differently-today-than-they-were-20-years-ago)? Basically, one just has to learn idiomatic preferences.

Comment: @KateBunting, what about ‘the wines of America’? It is the title of Leon D. Adams’s book.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, my question is about the difference between an adjective and of-genitive.

Comment: OK, you've found an exception; perhaps because wines are special products linked to a particular district, rather than a generic product like wheat or rice.

Comment: But the answer is the same: there is no easy way to determine which of apparently equally grammatical alternatives is going to be what is at times the much more idiomatic (often to the point of being the only acceptable) wording.  English team, England team, England's team, team of England.

Comment: @psmears Yes, it's more complicated and involves several factors, including definiteness and indefiniteness, and whether they can be seen as a list of individual definite things, animacy etc and more. So, in short, I agree with you (why there's a well placed *tend to* in there!)

Comment: Why, oh why, oh why is this is linked to such an inapt question?

Comment: @KateBunting, is 'American rice' more acceptable? I found many examples of 'Japanese cars' in Corpus of Contemporary American English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the difference between genitive and adjective is not discussed in the posts you mentioned. The similarity of the answer does not mean the similarity of the reasoning, does it? In fact, Quirk analyses the difference between 'the history of Europe' and 'European history' in his book.

Comment: You have already mentioned that option 2 is the correct one.

Comment: @KateBunting, yes. But, some comments above says all of the four options are not good.

Comment: 'European mountains are subtly different from the mountains of America' sounds as good as if not stylishly better (a loftier style?) than 'European mountains are subtly different from American mountains', while using 'ones' would sound totally underwhelming, awkward, used standalone. //  Your 4' similarly works, but rice being less inspirational than mountains (or wine) to most people, the loftier style is perhaps overblown.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, where does that loftiness come from? From its definiteness?

Comment: It's possibly related to origins, Norman-origin usages (pork, beef) usually being perceived as in a classier register than Anglo-Saxon (pig, cow). The Norman genitive is the periphrastic _of_ construction. 'The bridges of Paris' sounds more literary, more flowery, than the clinical 'the Paris / Parisian bridges'. This works also with related periphrastic _of_ constructions.  'The Flies Lord' probably wouldn't have received as much acclaim as 'The Lord of the Flies'.